# Ошибка выполнения плэйбука в ansible

Tags: python, шаблоны, ansible

Добрый день. Написал playbook который конфигурит zookeeper на удаленном хосте. При выполнении возникает ошибка в синтаксисе YAML. Не могу понять, где ошибка.

playbook:

```
---
- name: make changes in zoo.cfg
  hosts: zookeeper_node

  tasks:

    - name: Zookeeper configure  
      template: dest="{{zookeeper_conf_dir}}/zoo.cfg" 
      src=/home/ansible/k-ansible/template/zoo.cfg.j2
      become: yes
      user: ansible
```

ошибка:

```
ERROR! Syntax Error while loading YAML.


The error appears to have been in '/home/ansible/k-
ansible/playbooks/configure_zk.yml': line 4, column 1, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

  hosts: zookeeper_node

^ here
```

Благодарю за внимание!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Первая ошибка*:

```
  template: dest="{{zookeeper_conf_dir}}/zoo.cfg" 
  src=/home/ansible/k-ansible/template/zoo.cfg.j2
```

В YAML нельзя так переносить строку, нужно сделать отступ:

```
  template: dest="{{zookeeper_conf_dir}}/zoo.cfg" 
    src=/home/ansible/k-ansible/template/zoo.cfg.j2
```

А лучше не использовать упрощенную нотацию для передачи параметров, использовать полную YAML нотацию:

```
  template:
    dest: "{{zookeeper_conf_dir}}/zoo.cfg" 
    src: /home/ansible/k-ansible/template/zoo.cfg.j2
```

Так гораздо меньше вероятность сделать ошибку.

*Вторая ошибка*:

Одновременное использование двух модулей: `template` и `user` – видимо, вместо `user` вы хотели написать `remote_user` или `become_user`.